# CDI 2.0: Observing multiple events in one and the same observer instance

Tags: java, events, cdi, observers

I have two classes that fire two events (code comes from a junit test with private inner classes):

```
private static class EventEmitter1 { @Inject private Event<EventData1> event; }
private static class EventEmitter2 { @Inject private Event<EventData2> event; }
```

In my test EventData classes are trivial:

```
private class EventData1 { }
private class EventData2 { }
```

In a receiver class I want to wait until both events have been received, so I tried something like this:

```
private static class EventReceiver {
    private boolean eventData1Received = false;
    private boolean eventData2Received = false;

    private void receiveEventData1(@Observes EventData1 eventData) {
        LOGGER.debug("received " + eventData.getClass().getName());
        eventData1Received = true;
        handleReceivedEvents();
    }

    private void receiveEventData2(@Observes EventData2 eventData) {
        LOGGER.debug("received " + eventData.getClass().getName());
        eventData2Received = true;
        handleReceivedEvents();
    }

    private void handleReceivedEvents() {
        LOGGER.debug("eventData1Received: " + eventData1Received + ", eventData2Received: " + eventData2Received); 
    }
}
```

In my test method I manually select an instance for both emitter classes and fire an event for each instance. Moreover I manually select a Receiver instance.

```
@Test public void receiveEvents() {
    EventReceiver eventReceiver = CDI.current().select(EventReceiver.class).get();

    Instance<EventEmitter1> instanceEventEmitter1 = CDI.current().select(EventEmitter1.class);
    EventEmitter1 eventEmitter1 = instanceEventEmitter1.get();
    EventData1 eventData1 = new EventData1();
    eventEmitter1.event.fire(eventData1);

    Instance<EventEmitter2> instanceEventEmitter2 = CDI.current().select(EventEmitter2.class);
    EventEmitter2 eventEmitter2 = instanceEventEmitter2.get();
    EventData2 eventData2 = new EventData2();
    eventEmitter2.event.fire(eventData2);
}
```

Manual selection via CDI.current.select(...) should make sure the CDI mechanisms work.

My problem now is that this way three! EventReceiver instances get initialised. None of them ever has both eventDataXReceived fields set to true. What is the correct way to have the events being delivered to one and the same EventReceiver instance? Ideally EventReceiver should not be an (application scoped) singleton.

Thanx for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the EventReceiver an appropriate scope. Without a scope it is @Dependend, so for every event a new instance is created.

@ApplicationScoped should work fine.

Comment: Thanks for your immediate answer. Yes, @ApplicationScoped does the trick, but I don't want EventReceiver to be a singleton. I edited the question because I didn't make that clear in the original post. Is there another way to have multiple events being delivered to a single receiver instance? Target environment is JSE, not JEE.

Comment: There are some variations of that approach like forwarding the event to a singleton, or using static fields, or a custom scope that isnt singleton. But bascially all the same thing. What is the problem you have with @ApplicationScope? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Forwarding events sounds interesting, will try that soon. I want to bind UI component properties (JavaFX actually) in a loosely coupled manner. A controller waits until components are available and then binds component properties. Components may or may not become available in my case ...

Comment: I don't understand your concern with using app scope.

Comment: Afaik app scope makes the annotated type a singleton. In my case I want to use an UI component in multiple places. Think of a TableView displaying table A on the left, table B next to table A and so on. For each TableView I need an individual TableViewController, so TableViewController should not be singleton.

Answer (score 2):

I am afraid you will need to add a scope to your `EventReceiver` and `@ApplicationScoped` would normally be the go-to choice here.

You might add a secondary layer of logic which would help you determine where did this event come from and hence allow to determine if you already have both needed events registered (I suppose that is what you are after).

A possible way would be to store this kind of information in the *event payload*. Then, once you observer the event, extract this information and keep a collection of registered events. Upon addition into this collection, you might check whether you already have two events of given 'type'.

I hope you get the basic idea, to be more precise, I would need to know more about the code.

Last but not least, there is also an (crazy) option to [define your own scope](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.2/cdi-spec.html#defining_new_scope_type) which you can tailor to precisely fit your needs. That, however, requires some serious devotion and work.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that works for me:

1. Create an abstract event dispatcher type that observes the generic event type E that you are interested in. A generic approach could look like this:

```
public abstract class EventDispatcher<E>
{
    private Set<Consumer<E>> consumers = new HashSet<>();

    public Set<Consumer<E>> getConsumers() { return consumers; }

    protected void observe(@Observes E event)
    {
        consumers.forEach(consumer -> consumer.accept(event));
    }
}
```

Note: EventDispatcher provides `getConsumers()` that allows to register consumers that are interested in E.

2. Create a non abstract EventDispatcher for a custom Event E (`Event` in the following example) and give it a scope (`Singleton` in the following example):

```
    @Singleton private static class Dispatcher extends EventDispatcher<Event> { }
```

Note: A `private static` type completely suffices for it's tiny task.

3. Use (`@Inject`) your `Dispatcher` anywhere in your CDI application:

```
    @Inject private Dispatcher dispatcher;
```

4. Add a consumer to your `dispatcher` and do the things you think are appropriate when `Event` occurs in e.g. `onEvent(event)`:

```
        dispatcher.getConsumers().add(event -> onEvent(event));
```