# CDI events fire() create new observers instances

Tags: java, javafx, cdi

I'm writing a JavaFX application (JavaSE) with CDI (Weld). I'm trying to use CDI Events to replace the awful event system of JavaFX (JavaFX Properties).

I was able to let CDI create my JavaFX controllers properly. It means that when a FXML is loaded, the controller is created by CDI (using `FXLoader.setControllerFactory`). Unfortunately as soon as I added an @Observes in one controller, CDI started to create multiple instances this controller. that's crazy.

It appears that I just don't understand the proper semantic of `fire()`. Since when `fire()` will create observers ?! May be this have something to do with `@Dependent` scope.

I made an interceptor to send an event when some property change somewhere (in my case it is a background task that update a property Progress). (Don't pay attention to `ObservableSourceLiterral` and `@ObservableSource`, it's just to not fire events to everybody)

```
@ObservableProperty
@Interceptor
public class CDIPropertyWatcher {
    @Inject
    private Event<PropertyChangedEvent> listeners;

    @AroundInvoke
    public Object onPropertyCalled(InvocationContext ctx) throws Exception {
        String method = ctx.getMethod()
                .getName();
        if (method.startsWith("set")) {
            Object result = ctx.proceed();
            String propertyName = method.substring(3, 4)
                    .toLowerCase() + method.substring(4);
            listeners.select(new ObservableSourceLiterral(ctx.getTarget().getClass().getSuperclass()))
                    .fire(new PropertyChangedEvent(ctx.getTarget(), propertyName));

            return result;
        } else {
            return ctx.proceed();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the setter in my Task class:

```
@ObservableProperty
public void setProgress(double progress) {
      this.progress = progress;
}
```

This is a method of my controller responsible to receive the event:

```
public void onProgressTaskChanged(@Observes @ObservableSource(Task.class) PropertyChangedEvent evt)
{
        Double progress = evt.getSource(Task.class).getProgress();
        System.out.println("onProgressTaskChanged "+progress+" "+this);
        if (progressBar!=null)
        {
            Platform.runLater(() -> progressBar.setProgress(progress));
        }
}
```

I expect that when I fire an event, it is received by the actual existing observers, and not create new ones.

Comment: Not fluent in CDI, but [this documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/2.0/cdi-spec.html#conditional_observer_methods) would seem to indicate the `@Dependent` scope is the problem.

Comment: Took a quick peak at the docs. Never used cdi. But from what you have there, slaw and the docs it looks like ctx.gettarget() creates new instances of the target object when dependent is specified.  May need to rework the observablesourceliteral and  propertychangedevent if you need dependent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the trick here is indeed the `@Dependent` scope of a bean with observer.

According to specification, there will always be new instance created to receive the notification and destroyed afterwards. Relevant parts of spec are [5.5.6 Invocation of observer methods](https://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/2.0/cdi-spec.html#observers_method_invocation) and [6.4.2 Destruction of objects with scope @Dependent](https://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/2.0/cdi-spec.html#dependent_destruction).

To explain why it behaves like this - for other (normal) scopes, you always have 0 or 1 instance of that given bean within a context and notification can easily pick the existing one or create new and store it in the context. Whereas with `@Dependent` you can have 0 to n instances which would lead to multiple notifications per event fired if this behaved differently.

Try using some normal scope (application/request/session/conversation) instead and you should get the behaviour you expect.

Comment: I think I'm precisely where CDI have some limits. Ideally I would have to create my own Scope that fit the way JavaFX works. But that's way too complicated. Available scopes are more for Java EE not Java SE. Here, there is no requests, no session, no conversation and it is not a singleton, it's just widgets that leave and die depending on the GUI state. CDI does not provide scope for that.

Comment: In SE request scope can be manually started/stopped and is often used to capture a shorter duration context that you can have control over. There is either interceptor based approach or through a built-in bean (look [here](https://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/2.0/cdi-spec.html#activating_request_context)). Otherwise you would need you own scope indeed, [here](https://github.com/weld/command-context-example) is a tiny project that shows custom scope.

Comment: SE request scope, mmh I will investigate that... thanks a lot.

Comment: ooooh gosh: As soon as I use `@RequestScoped` on my controller it becomes a CDI proxy, so it is a subclass. And guess what ? The annotation `@FXML` no longer work. It seems that is a using `setControllerFactory` and let the factory return a subclass of the controller class specified in the FXML is a dead end. I can opt to remove the controller class in the FXML and use setController may be...

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar scenario. What about the following idea?

```
@Singleton
public class Observer<E>
{
  private Set<Consumer<E>> consumers = new HashSet<>();
  public void addConsumer(Consumer<E> consumer) { ... }
  void observe(@Oberves E event)
  {
    // propagate event to all consumers
    consumers.forEach(consumer -> consumer.accept(event));
  }
}
```

You should be able to inject an observer, add consumer(s) to it and the consumers will be notified when the observe method propagates the event.

Looks like this is working for me.

[edit] Here is a more detailed description for my approach: [observing multiple events in one and the same observer instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38174501/cdi-2-0-observing-multiple-events-in-one-and-the-same-observer-instance/67038033#67038033)